# How to group value within a certain date range or every certain days in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, sum

For example table would be:

```
Customer   OrderDate   OrderAmt
--------   ----------  ---------
A1          20140101      920.00
A2          20140111      301.00
A2          20140123      530.00
A1          20140109      800.00
A3          20140110      500.00
A1          20140115      783.00
A3          20140217      500.00
A1          20140219     1650.00
A1          20140225      780.00
...
A3          20140901      637.00
```

I want to group them and calculate the sum(OrderAmt) within every 20 days and group by customer start from 20140101.

Comment: orderdate should be a date/datetime-type field. Looks like it's varchar, which means you're in for a VERY nasty time getting this to work.

Comment: It's great that you included samples of your source data!  Why don't you also post some examples showing what you expect the output to look like, as well, based on the sample data you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the OrderDate is a numeric field (not varchar). I'm also assuming that you don't need to go much more than a year in the future. If you want the gaps shown, keep the left join, if you don't want the gaps, then make it an inner join. (You can also make the hardcoded date a variable of where to start, I just kept it as the 20140101 that you mentioned.

```
with Numbers as 
(Select 0 as Num 
    UNION ALL 
 Select Num+1 
 FROM Numbers 
 WHERE Num+1<= 20
)
, DateList AS
(Select  Year(DateAdd(dd,20*(Num), Cast('2014-01-01' as date))) * 10000+Month(DateAdd(dd,20*(Num), Cast('2014-01-01' as date)))*100+Day(DateAdd(dd,20*(Num), Cast('2014-01-01' as date))) Groupingdatemin
, Year(DateAdd(dd,20*(Num+1)-1, Cast('2014-01-01' as date)))*10000+ MONTH(DateAdd(dd,20*(Num+1)-1, Cast('2014-01-01' as date)))*100+DAY(DateAdd(dd,20*(Num+1)-1, Cast('2014-01-01' as date))) Groupingdatemax
from Numbers
) 
select Customer, sum(orderamt), Groupingdatemin, Groupingdatemax from DateLIst d LEFT JOIN 
    <yourtable> t on t.orderdate between d.Groupingdatemin and d.Groupingdatemax
group by customer, Groupingdatemin, Groupingdatemax
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can accomplish what you describe with a pretty simple `DATEDIFF()` / `GROUP BY` operation, as below: whether or not that is actually what you want might be another question.  I suspect that the DateBucket calculation might actually be something else ...

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpCustomer (Customer VARCHAR(2), OrderDate VARCHAR(10), OrderAmt DECIMAL(6,2))

INSERT INTO #tmpCustomer (Customer, OrderDate, OrderAmt)


SELECT 'A1',20140101,      920.00 UNION
SELECT 'A2',20140111,      301.00 UNION
SELECT 'A2',20140123,      530.00 UNION
SELECT 'A1',20140109,      800.00 UNION
SELECT 'A3',20140110,      500.00 UNION
SELECT 'A1',20140115,      783.00 UNION
SELECT 'A3',20140217,      500.00 UNION
SELECT 'A1',20140219,     1650.00 UNION
SELECT 'A1',20140225,      780.00 UNION
SELECT 'A3',20140901,      637.00


SELECT 
    Customer, 
    (DATEDIFF(day, '1/1/2014', CAST(OrderDate AS DATE)) / 20) + 1 AS DateBucket, 
    SUM(OrderAmt) SumOrderAmt
FROM #tmpCustomer
GROUP BY Customer, (DATEDIFF(day, '1/1/2014', CAST(OrderDate AS DATE)) / 20) + 1
ORDER BY Customer, DateBucket
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:
(1) Create some sort of guide hold the '20 day groups' information.  A Recursive CTE does this pretty well, and
(2) Recast that varchar date as an actual date for comparison purposes.

Then it's just joining the order data into that daterange grouping and summing the order amounts.

```
-------------------------
-- Here i'm just recreating your example
-------------------------
DECLARE @customerOrder TABLE (Customer varchar(2), OrderDate varchar(8), OrderAmt decimal(8,2))
INSERT INTO @customerOrder (Customer, OrderDate, OrderAmt)
VALUES
    ('A1', '20140101', 920.00),
    ('A2', '20140111', 301.00),
    ('A2', '20140123', 530.00),
    ('A1', '20140109', 800.00),
    ('A3', '20140110', 500.00),
    ('A1', '20140115', 783.00),
    ('A3', '20140217', 500.00),
    ('A1', '20140219', 1650.00),
    ('A1', '20140225', 780.00),
    ('A3', '20140901', 637.00)

-------------------------
-- Set up a table that lists off 20 day periods starting from 1/1/2014
-------------------------
DECLARE @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime; 

SET @startDate = {d N'2014-01-01'}; 
SET @endDate   = {d N'2014-12-31'}; 

WITH [dates] ([Sequence], [startDate], [maxExcludedDate]) AS 
   (SELECT 1 AS [Sequence] 
          ,@startDate AS [startDate] 
          ,DATEADD(d, 20, @startDate) AS [maxExcludedDate] 

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Sequence + 1 AS Sequence 
          ,DATEADD(d, 20, [startDate]) AS [startDate] 
          ,DATEADD(d, 40, [startDate]) AS [maxExcludedDate]
    FROM [dates] 
    WHERE [startDate] < @endDate
) 
, dateFrame AS
( 
    SELECT 
          [startDate] 
          ,[maxExcludedDate]

    FROM [dates] 
)
-------------------------
-- Set up a table that holds the orderDates as actual dates
-------------------------
, castData AS
(
    SELECT
        cast(orderdate as datetime) castDate
        ,OrderAmt
    FROM @customerOrder
)

-------------------------
-- JOIN and sum.
-------------------------
SELECT
    [startDate]
    , Sum(OrderAmt) perodAmt
FROM
    dateFrame df

    left join castData cd
        on cd.castDate >= df.startDate
        and cd.castDate < df.maxExcludedDate
GROUP BY
    [startDate]

ORDER by
    [startDate]
```